# Как в своей странице открыть другую?

Tags: javascript, dom

Как в своей странице открыть другую и получить доступ к её DOM?
Мне нужно отслеживать клики по кнопкам и инпутам во встроенной странице.

Comment: Страница на том же домене? Если нет, то никак. То есть, открыть-то не вопрос, обычный iframe. А вот получить доступ к DOM - нет.

Comment: @yaant встраиваемая страница открыта на localhost, а моя работает на Electronjs. Тоесть это desktop-приложение.

Comment: С электроном дела не имел, но гугль подсказывает, что там у `BrowserWindow` есть в параметре `webpreferences` есть свойство `websecurity`, которое можно установить в `false`... А еще есть атрибут `disablewebsecurity` у тэга `webview`.